# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

Tags: c#

hey i'm kinda new to unity and i've been trying butt off to get this error right but i just can't seem to get it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DropZone : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public GameObject GameBoard;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (GameBoard.GetComponent<Rules>().YourTurna = false)
        {
            DropZone = null;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("OnPointerEnter");
        if (eventData.pointerDrag == null)
            return;

        Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();
        if (d != null)
        {
            d.placeholderParent = this.transform;
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("OnPointerExit");
        if (eventData.pointerDrag == null)
            return;

        Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();
        if (d != null && d.placeholderParent == this.transform)
        {
            d.placeholderParent = d.parentToReturnTo;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(eventData.pointerDrag.name + " was dropped on " + gameObject.name);
        Draggable d = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<Draggable>();
        if (d != null)
        {
            d.parentToReturnTo = this.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

so i'm trying to get it to see if it's the players turn, if not it's supose to keep the player from moving around his cards on the gameboard. my problem is that i keep getting the error

Assets/DropZone.cs(16,25): error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer

i am unsure what this is refuring to because i've tried changing the bool to an int, a var, ect. and i keep geting this error. if anyone can help me out, i'd be greatful.

Comment: Try including line numbers for starters. Your code makes no sense as is. If you extract `YourTurn` to `Rules` why extract it again and compare? It's no good to compare the wrong types (bool to int, fx). Can you post where you define `YourTurn`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set a class definition of `DropZone` to null instead of the actual thing.

Comment: `DropZone` is coloured thus because of the casing. It's SO's doing and it could very well just be a property. We don't know though, cause it's not included in the code.

Comment: Turns out `DropZone` actually is a class. @OwenJames is right in his assumption - you cannot null a class from within itself. You would have to null it where it's instantiated in the first place. You'd have to instantiate the `GameBoard` in `Start()` I suppose. Have you programmed C# before starting on Unity?

Comment: no, i started with C# when i started unity :3 but i think i understand what you guys are saying. I'm going to play around with it and look at a few more tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If that method is in class `DropZone`, then you are trying to set a class definition of `DropZone` to `null`, which is not posible and doesn't make any sense. What you are probably *trying* to do is set the instance of the active dropZone to `null` from within it self, which would look something like:

```
this = null;
```

which is *not posible* because you are trying to set a class instance to `null` from within itself.

What you should do is set the instance of `DropZone` to `null` where ever it is created/contained, which would look something like:

```
var dropZone = new DropZone();
// ...

if (/* Conditions */)
    dropZone = null;
```

Hope this helped! Might be a little confusing as I do not actually use Unity.

Comment: i think i understand, not sure how to fix it but thanks for clearing it up a bit :3

Comment: @user5283605 No problem! If this or any other answer was the solution to your problem please remember to mark it as correct. Happy coding :)